# JDBC Template exception table or view does not exist but it actually exists

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to get some data from Oracle DB using Spring JDBCTemplate:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM snow.ar_incident WHERE ROWNUM < 10";

    Map<String, List<Attachment>> map = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<Map<String, List<Attachment>>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<Attachment>> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            Map<String, List<Attachment>> map = new HashMap<>();
            //Mapping results to map
            return map;
        }
    });
```

But I'm always getting an exception only for `ar_incidient` table:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * from
>   snow.ar_incident WHERE ROWNUM < 10]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
>   exist

This code works perfectly fine for other tables but not for this one. I also tried to get data from this table using core Java sql connection:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, user, pass);    
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();   
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from snow.ar_incident WHERE ROWNUM < 10");
```

And it worked without a problem, same when I run the query in SQL Developer. I have checked many times connection details for the both solutions and they are identical. Why can't I access `ar_incident` table using JDBCTemplate?

Comment: does it throws error even if you simplify the query into `SELECT * FROM ar_incident` ?

Comment: Yes, always when I try to use `ar_incident` table.

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` does the same as you do. Also the error comes from the driver not Spring. So either the table/view really doesn't exists or you don't have the correct privileges or you are not looking at the database you think you are looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating JDBC driver to newer version all problems disappeared.

Comment: Do you recall which version didn't work, and which version did?

Comment: @Nate I had this problem with `OJDBC6` and it was solved when I moved to `OJDBC8`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if **grants** are there and if you need to prefix table name with **schema.table_name**.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by the fact that you dont have select privileges on that specific table

```
grant select on snow.ar_incident to your_user;
```

Comment: I don't think so because I run the query in SQL Developer for the same user and it worked.

Comment: he said that is working if he uses java JDBC, so that's not the problem